# UDP send() to localhost under Winsock throwing away packets?

Tags: c++, c, udp, send, winsock2

Scenario is rather simple... not allowed to use "`sendto()`" so using "`send()`" instead...

Under `winsock2.2`, normal operation on an brand new i7 machine running  `Windows 7 Professional`...

Using `SOCK_DGRAM` socket, Client and Server console applications connect over `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`) to test things ...

Have to use packets of constant size...

Client socket uses `connect()`, Server socket uses `bind()`...

Client sends N packets using series of `BLOCKING` `send()` calls. Server only uses `ioctlsocket` call with `FIONREAD`, running in a `while` loop to constantly `printf()` number of bytes awaiting to be received...

**PACKETS GET LOST UNLESS I PUT `SLEEP()` WITH CONSIDERABLE AMMOUNT OF  TIME...** *What I mean is the number of bytes on the receiving socket differs  between runs if I do not use `SLEEP()`...*

Have played with changing buffer sizes, situation did not change much, except now there is no overflow, but the problem with the delay remains the same ...

I have seen many discussions about the issue between `send()` and `recv()`, but in this scenario, `recv()` is not even involved...

Thoughts anyone?

---

(P.S. The constraints under which I am programming are required for reasons beyond my control, so no `WSA`, `.NET`, `MFC`, `STL`, `BOOST`, `QT` or other stuff)

---

It is NOT an issue of buffer overflow for three reasons:

1. Both incoming and outgoing buffers are set and checked to be
   significantly larger than ALL of the information being sent.

   2. There is no `recv()`, only checking of the incoming buffer via `ioctl()` call, recv() is called long after, upon user input.
   3. When `Sleep()` of `>40ms` is added between `send()`-s, the whole thing works, i.e. if there was an overflow no ammount of
      `Sleep()` would have helped (`again, see point (2)` )

Comment: UDP is not a guaranteed delivery protocol. Even on localhost. Not a single packet you ever send with UDP to any recipient is guaranteed to be delivered anywhere. If you don't want packet loss, don't use UDP. End of story.

Comment: Ok, not to use UDP, but then how do I broadcast and multicast on another widely available protocol? Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Does this behave the same on other OS's as well?

Comment: Pretty much the same on all OSes. UDP gives no guarantees, whatsoever. That's part of it's charm.

Comment: So how to get unicast , broadcast and multicast without being too charmed and having to reduce the bandwidth?

Comment: In UDP, if you never call `recv()` or `recvfrom()` then inbound packets will stay in the socket's buffer and when it fills up then subsequent packets will be dropped.  Unlike TCP, which will block the sender instead.

Comment: No there no easy way to do "broadcast and multicast" with guaranteed delivery to any recipient. Internetworking fundamentals don't work this way. Large volume broadcasters like Youtube have invested tens of thousands of person-years writing millions lines of code implementing smart, adaptive broadcasting protocols that heuristically adjust themselves to available bandwidth, and automatically recover from occasional packet drops.

Comment: Remy, the packets are much smaller than the sending and the receiving socket buffer, and they simply do not reach the receiving socket's buffer. They are lost on the sending end somehow unless I make the code sleep for at least 15 ms between sends... 15!!!

Comment: UDP packets can be dropped at any time for any reason. Nothing further needs be said. Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Comment: Sam, I get what you are saying, but there seems to be a bug of some kind or uncarefull programming on the part of kernel developers ? because it is not that the packets do not get delived or get lost in the process , they appear not to be sent... as if there is only one slot that does the preparation for sending and any data arriving while preparation is being done just gets thrown away... I mean sure, do not promise delivery, do not deal with network architecture and transport layers, but at least get the data out...

Comment: 15 ms is suspiciously close to the default timer tick. So... the problem may be on the receiver side, as Remy suggested.

Comment: @AFour if send() returns a non-error return value, then the packet has definitely been "sent" (where "sent" in this case is defined to mean "has been successfully placed into the UDP socket's outgoing-data-buffer").  Whether or not the packet ever arrives at its destination is a very different question, and it's entirely possible (and expected) that it might not ever arrive anywhere.  UDP is very much a "best effort" protocol, which makes no guarantees about anything.

Comment: @ddbug, both sides have 1MB buffer set (and verified via getsockopt) and packets are 200 bytes each, about 100 of them, so there should be no overflow on any side, plus the receiving side does not go to recv(), it just waits and checks how many bytes are in the buffer via ioctl call...

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, can it be that the packet has been placed into udp socket's outgoing data buffer and never reached the actual network? Is there some mechanism that would result in the packet simply being thrown out of the buffer after it has been placed there?

Comment: How about specifying NODELAY and other latency & Nagle related parameters?

Comment: @AFour I'm not aware of such a mechanism, but UDP allows the implementers to drop packets whenever they feel like doing so, for any reason, so there's nothing stopping Microsoft from doing so if they want to.

Comment: @ddbug TCP_NODELAY/Nagle is a TCP-specific thing, it's unrelated to UDP.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, so the only option is S.U.A.E.I. ? (i.e. ShutUpAndEatIt :) )?

Comment: Possibly; on the other hand if you suspect the behavior is Windows-specific, you could try running your program on another OS (e.g. Linux or MacOS/X) and see if the fault occurs there also.  If it also occurs there, that suggests that the problem is not Windows-specific and therefore might be related to something in your program.  If it only occurs under Windows (or only on one particular Windows machine), that suggest the behavior is related to that OS or that hardware in particular.

Answer (score 0):

> PACKETS GET LOST UNLESS I PUT SLEEP() WITH CONSIDERABLE AMMOUNT OF
>   TIME... What I mean is the number of bytes on the receiving socket
>   differs between runs if I do not use SLEEP()...

This is expected behavior; as others have said in the comments, UDP packets can and do get dropped for any reason.  In the context of localhost-only communication, however, the reason is usually that a fixed-size packet buffer somewhere is full and can't hold the incoming UDP packet.  Note that UDP has no concept of flow control, so if your receiving program can't keep up with your sending program, packet loss is definitely going to occur as soon as the buffers get full.

As for what to do about it, the insert-a-call-to-sleep() solution isn't particularly good because you have no good way of knowing what the "right" sleep-duration ought to be.  (To short a sleep() and you'll still drop packets; too long a sleep() and you're transferring data more slowly than you might otherwise do; and of course the "best" value will likely vary from one computer to the next, or one moment to the next, in non-obvious ways).

One thing you could do is switch to a different transport protocol such as TCP, or (since you're only communicating within localhost), a simple pipe or socketpair.  These protocols have the lossless FIFO semantics that you are looking for, so they might be the right tool for the job.

Assuming you are required to use UDP, however, UDP packet loss will be a fact of life for you, but there are some things you can do to reduce packet loss:

1. send() in blocking mode, or if using non-blocking send(), be sure to wait until the UDP socket select()'s as ready-for-write before calling send().  (I know you said you send() in blocking mode; I'm just including this for completeness)
2. Make your SO_RCVBUF setting as large as possible on the receiving UDP socket(s).  The larger the buffer, the lower the chance of it filling up to capacity.
3. In the receiving program, be sure that the thread that calls recv() does nothing else that would ever hold it off from getting back to the next recv() call.  In particular, no blocking operations (even printf() is a blocking operation that can slow your thread down, especially under Windows where the DOS prompt is infamous for slow scrolling under load)
4. Run your receiver's network recv() loop in a separate thread that does nothing else but call recv() and place the received data into a FIFO queue (or other shared data structure) somewhere.  Then another thread can do the less time-critical work of examining and parsing the data in the FIFO, without fear of causing a dropped packet.
5. Run the UDP-receive thread at the highest priority you can convince the OS to let you run at.  The fewer other tasks that can hold of the UDP-receive thread, the fewer opportunities for packets to get dropped during those hold-off periods.

Just keep in mind that no matter how clever you are at reducing the chances for UDP packet loss, UDP packet loss will still happen.  So regardless you need to come up with a design that allows your programs to still function in a reasonably useful manner even when packets are lost.  This could be done by implementing some kind of automatic-resend mechanism, or (depending on what you are trying to accomplish) by designing the protocol such that packet loss can simply be ignored.

Comment: Btw if, during your attempts to work around UDP's shortcomings, you notice that you are slowly re-implementing all of the features of TCP, one at a time... that's good evidence that you should probably just use TCP instead :)

Comment: Ofcorse, if I design my own way to work around UDP's shortcommings I might in the end re-implement all the features of TCP :) but then I will have a reliable protocol that might be a bit faster and will also have broadcasting and multicasting abilities ;)

Comment: Did all of the suggestions already, now even added select() (in case the socket would be running non-blocking sends one day) , but that does not help, without pausing the between sends the situation is simply terrible... 90% loss at times... High performance system it is NOT ;¬(

Comment: In this case buffers are 10 times bigger than the total amount of data being sent / received ... no chance of them being overflown... but the packet loss is still terrible and of all , on localhost

Comment: And it is clean win7 , @out of the box@

Comment: A buffer 10 times bigger than an individual packet will overflow anytime the sender send()s 11 packets before the receiver recv()s a packet.

Comment: @AFour Can you test on Win7 SP1, clean and/or fully updated? Win7 without SP is too old.

Comment: @ddbug, it is fully updated one with the SP... I think I will need to install Wireshark or something to test my solutions ...

Comment: "A buffer 10 times bigger than an individual packet will overflow anytime the sender send()s 11 packets before the receiver recv()s a packet" ... I have 1MB sending and 1MB receiving buffer set, I am sending three packets of 256 bytes, first one arrives, third arrives, second does not... or sometimes second and third arrive and first does not... It is not an issure of overflow, something is wrong with the transport... if it was an issue of overflow, (and since I am not even calling recv() on the other side, only ioctl) it would not work after sleep(), but it does if sleep() is in

Comment: It seems like implementation of winsock was done in an extremely sloppy way and nobody tried to fix it from the beginning...