# Are UDP packets guaranteed when sent over a port within on machine?

Tags: sockets, networking, udp

I'm aware that when two machines communicate via UDP, the packets they send are not guaranteed to be delivered in order, or delivered at all for that matter.

However, what I'm wondering, is if two programmes on the same machine are communicating via UDP, are the packets guaranteed to be delivered in order, or guaranteed at all, considering there is no network routing involved (at least to my knowledge)?

As an example, I have a program, A, running on my machine sending ~200 packets per second to a port via UDP on the IP 127.0.0.1, and another program, B, on the same machine, listening for these packets and doing something with them. Is it guaranteed that B will 'hear' all the packets A sent, and will they always be heard in the order A sent them?

Comment: There is never a guarantee of packet delivery under UDP, not even on localhost -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40185556/udp-send-to-localhost-under-winsock-throwing-away-packets/40187014#40187014

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that UDP is designed as no guaranteed. For UDP, it doesn't know whether the two sides of the connection are in the same PC. And it's not a good idea to write some more specific code for that circumstance includ UDP. If you really want it to be reliable, you can control it by yourself.